# Activation of Grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

For activating Grignard reagents, iodine or 1,2-dibromoethane are usually added, and these lead to the formation of $\ce{MgI2}$ or $\ce{MgBr2}$ respectively . Why can these $\ce{MgI2}$ and $\ce{MgBr2}$ activate Grignard reagents? If possible, please show me the literature.

Comment: These ingredients are not "activating the gringard reagent" they are activating the magnesium. Some compounds we want to make Grignards from are not very reactive and it helps to activate the magnesium surface so those reactions happen faster. Small, reactive molecules are good at this. Though sometimes even this isn't enough.

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reagent)?

> Typically the reaction to form Grignard reagents involves the use of magnesium ribbon. **All magnesium is coated with a passivating layer of magnesium oxide, which inhibits reactions with the organic halide.** Many methods have been developed to weaken this passivating layer, thereby exposing highly reactive magnesium to the organic halide. Mechanical methods include crushing of the Mg pieces in situ, rapid stirring, and sonication. **Iodine, methyl iodide, and 1,2-dibromoethane are common activating agents. The use of 1,2-dibromoethane is advantageous as its action can be monitored by the observation of bubbles of ethylene.** Furthermore, the side-products are innocuous:
>
> $$\ce{Mg + BrC2H4Br → C2H4 ^ + MgBr2}$$
> The amount of Mg consumed by these activating agents is usually insignificant. A small amount of mercuric chloride will amalgamate the surface of the metal, enhancing its reactivity. Addition of preformed Grignard reagent is often used as the initiator.
>
> Specially activated magnesium, such as Rieke magnesium, circumvents this problem. The oxide layer can also be broken up using ultrasound, using a stirring rod to scratch the oxidized layer off, or by adding a few drops of iodine or 1,2-Diiodoethane. Another option is to use sublimed magnesium or magnesium anthracene.

With the formation of ethylene, the oxide layer is somewhat etched exposing the underlying metal which can react with the bromoderivative. See this previous [chem.SE question.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/146148/will-a-crystal-of-iodine-lower-the-yield-of-an-grignard-reaction)

For literature, see:

Reactivity of Magnesium Surfaces during the Formation of Grignard Reagents
Cynthia E. Teerlinck and Walter J. Bowyer, The Journal of Organic Chemistry **1996** 61 (3), 1059-1064, DOI: [10.1021/jo951626o](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo951626o)